# Arduino Nano stucks on uploading

Tags: serial, arduino-nano, usb, uploading

I'm trying to upload an simple blink sketch to my Arduino Nano, which not used for a while.

As I remember, I uploaded an sketch to control RF module, at the last time I used. Now, when I connect my Arduino Nano, I 'm getting error message every second, from my serial monitor saying the the RF communication cant start, because I have disconnected all connections to the RF module.

It seems the Nano is working, and the Nano driver is working properly. I tried resetting manually, and uploading many times with random timings. But up to now, the sketch not uploaded, and waiting. When I press reset button while uploading, Arduino shows me the error it cant communicate.

I think the Arduino IDE not getting enough time to upload from serial, because it's busy all the time.

Is there any way to wipe out the existing sketch from Nano? or any working solution to upload my new empty sketch or simple blink sample? It's a big help if anyone can shed me some light to make my Nano work again.

Comment: select "Old bootloader" in Tools menu

Comment: @Juraj, I'm unable to find 'Old bootloader' in tools menu. You mean 'Burn bootloader'?

Comment: @Juraj, Ok I found it on sub menu and worked great! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Juraj I solved it thank you

Comment: You should use the "That solved my problem" button, not write an answer

Comment: @Juraj, There is no button available to me?

Comment: it should be in the box above the question

Comment: Edit and delete buttons are available, nothing else?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by selecting,

Tools > Processor > ATMega (Old bootloader)

@Juraj, Thank you for suggestion.